# How to configure Jenkinsfile to build maven modules in parallel?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build all my maven modules in parallel using Jenkins. I need to configure this in my Jenkinsfile. I have already tried the following:

```
node('cicd-build') {
    println("Pipeline to run - ${utils.pipelineToRun}")
    def branch = env.BRANCH_NAME
    println("Branch - ${branch}")

        stage('Checkout') {
            scmCheckout {
                deleteWorkspace = 'true'
                maven_version = 'maven 3.6'
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            javaCompile {
                goals = "clean install -T 4"
            }
        }
```

But the clean install -T 4 is not being applied on the Jenkins pipeline

Comment: `withMaven(...) { sh "mvn -T .."}`

Comment: What I don't understand: `..on the Jenkins pipeline`...you have a single step applied which means a single process...The modules will be build in parallel based on `-T ...` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I actually just thought the -T 10 would pick up the maven command on Jenkins but its not working. I know that there are parallel runs which can be configured on jenkins like for different tasks and branches. But is the same thing possible to do with maven modules too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do what Chetan did but I would add the -B parameter as well

```
-B, --batch-mode
Run in non-interactive (batch) mode
```

that would do:

```
mvn -B -T 4 clean install
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to give a try with this

```
stage('Build') {
    steps {
        sh 'mvn -T 4 clean install'
    }
}
```